# Laravel ajax url not working on production server

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, deployment, routes

I have this ajax request on my Laravel Project (this is a simple version but it is working):

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
            url: '/admin/lessons/addMember/licenseMemberId', // This is the url we gave in the route
            data: {'licenseMemberId' : id},
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response);

                if ($.trim(response)) {
                    var actualMembers = document.getElementById("actual-member");
                }
                $('#membersModal').modal('hide');
            },  
        });
```

When I work locally and I use php artisan serve the ajax call works, but when i deploy to my production server doesn't (because the path /admin/lessons/addMember/licenseMemberId is not the full path in the server).
The best way shoud be using the route, but I don't know how.
This is the routing table:

```
web                                          |
|        | POST      | admin/lessons/addMember/{licenseMemberId}                     | lessons.addMember               | App\Http\Controllers\admin\LessonController@addMember
```

Is there a way to use the laravel route with the paramether? If not, how can I do?

Comment: In post method you can send the {licenseMemberId} with ajax data parameter, not route parameter.

Comment: Can you post your controller method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use URLs in Laravel the way you use it in vanila php or html, use the [URL function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls), this function ensures that your route is pointing currectly to the project root, in your case you can do something like this

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: '{{URL::to('/admin/lessons/addMember/')}}' + id, 
// Laravel will print the url and you just need to concat your id to it
        success: function(response){ 
            console.log(response);

            if ($.trim(response)) {
                var actualMembers = document.getElementById("actual-member");
            }
            $('#membersModal').modal('hide');
        },  
    });
```

Notice that im using GET as you seem to be retrieving data and not POSTING it, however if you need to post it, the MisaGH answer is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Do not receive the parameter in route.

URL should be : `/admin/lessons/addMember`

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
            url: '/admin/lessons/addMember', // This is the url we gave in the route
            data: {'licenseMemberId' : id},
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response);

                if ($.trim(response)) {
                    var actualMembers = document.getElementById("actual-member");
                }
                $('#membersModal').modal('hide');
            },  
        });
```

And the controller:

```
$member_id = request('licenseMemberId');
```

Comment: Thank you but when I put your code in production server still don work, I dot this console error: http://www.bosco.com/admin/lessons/addMember/licenseMemberId  -->not found, the problem is that my project is in a subdirectory it should be http://www.bosco.com/sg3000/public//admin/lessons/addMember/licenseMemberId

Comment: If /sg3000/public is really part of your public url, you need to go there...  bit strange though

Comment: so the best practice is not to pass the parameters with route parameter when I have a POST method? Or it is good only when I use it in an ajax script? Because I use this route also in others parts of my code, but normal php code...

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But I think this approach for ajax calls is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The real route is

```
admin/lessons/addMember/{licenseMemberId}
```

so in javascript you need to call

```
'/admin/lessons/addMember/' + id
```

where id is a variable. In the controller you can use the id getting

```
Input::get('licenseMemberId') or $request->get('licenseMemberId');
```